# How to rewrite code to avoid using global arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I have the following piece of code:

```php
$item_list = array();
$item_list['PENCIL']   = "Utility used to write.";
$item_list['CAR']      = "A means of transportation.";

function item_exists($name) {
    global $item_list;

    return isset($item_list[$name]);
}

function get_item_description($name) {
    global $item_list;

    return ( item_exists($name) ? $item_list[$name] : "Unknown item." );
}
```

On top of the file an array is defined which contains a list of items with descriptions, which are used by multiple functions. The array is never modified in the functions, it is only used as read-only data. If I want to rewrite this piece of code to avoid using global variables, what is the nicest way to do this?

Comment: Why not pass the list into the function along with name?

Comment: @JonStirling I think the point is to use them afterwards as well (in various parts of the script). While passing it as an argument to each and every function is possible, PHP provides a better solution in the form of constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encapsulate your data in a class. This is especially appropriate if you are planning to do other operations with the `$item_list`.

Something along these lines should get you started:

```
<?php
class Items
{
    private $item_list = array(
        'PENCIL' => "Utility used to write.",
        'CAR'    => "A means of transportation."
    );

    private function exists($name) {
        return isset( $this->item_list[$name]);
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return ( $this->exists($name) ? $this->item_list[$name] : "Unknown item." );
    }

    public function __set( $key, $value) {
        $this->item_list[ $key ] = $value;
    }
}

$items = new Items;
echo $items->PENCIL . "\n"; // __get() will be called to retrieve this element's value
echo $items->IDUNNO . "\n";
$items->IDUNNO = "Not an unknown item.";
echo $items->IDUNNO . "\n";
```

[Try it out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/so9u5T)

Comment: You should add the public/protected etc to your class variables and functions.

Comment: @Truth Good point, updated. I also added an example of using `__set` to dynamically add items to the list.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[constants](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)** and [`define()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) to define constants to be used throughout the script.

```
define('PENCIL', 'Utility used to write.');
define('CAR', 'A means of transportation.');

function item_exists($name) {
    return defined($name);
}
function get_item_description($name) {
    return item_exists($name) ? constant($name) : "Unknown Item";
}
```

Comment: This allows unrelated information to be correlated together. For example, `echo get_item_description( 'PHP_VERSION');` will print the current PHP version, which is clearly not an element in the `$item_list`.

Comment: Point taken. Will keep the answer for future reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have thought of using constants indeed, but in my case `item_exists()` may only return true if the item is in the list. Not if it is defined as a constant somewhere else in the application. Too bad no such thing as constant arrays exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could hard-code the array into every function. This is the easiest solution, but I think everybody agrees that is the worst one. It is redundant and can lead to errors ...

Another way could be creating a class and storing the array in a private variable:

```
class ItemList {
  private $list = ...

  function exists(...) { if ($this->list[..]) ... }
...
}
```

But I wonder why you want to do this? In my opinion, this is a perfectly valid case to use global variables... They are not as evil as everybody says.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that, reusable and loosely coupled

```
class ItemList {

    private var $item_list = array();

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->item_list[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return (isset($this->item_list[$name]) ? $this->item_list[$name] : "Unknown item.");
    }

}

$item_list = new ItemList();
$item_list->PENCIL = "Utility used to write.";
$item_list->CAR = "A means of transportation.";
echo $item_list->PENCIL;
echo $item_list->SO;
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. In my case it would be ok to add the items in the constructor I guess, because it is a fixed list. It is not modified by the script.